# manage-site-redirects - The requested operation is not supported for this site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, redirect

I followed the steps mentioned in the below MS Article. However, it is not working for me.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects

What I did for testing:

1. created a new site: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abc (communication site template)
2. renamed it to: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abcNew
3. Ran the script: Remove-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abc

However, I'm getting an error.
**Error**: "The requested operation is not supported for site: [https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abc."](https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abc.%22)

Is it that the site: "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abcNew" must be deleted so that the old URL can be released?
If not, then why the command is not working?

Comment: Did you apply any retention policy to the old or new URL for the site?

Comment: yes... there was. However, even after removing the retention, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a retention compliance policy that would not allow the site to be deleted. I had to remove the lock

> set-SPOSite https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abc -LockState Unlock

then exempt the site from the retention policy (pureview portal)
and
then I was finally able to delete the site.